# PrimeNG Table not displaying display name or my array in the table body

Tags: angular, primeng

I have an HTML component:

```
<p-table [value]="results1" [tableStyle]="{ 'min-width': '30rem' }">
 <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-user>
 <tr>
 <th>Groups for {{user.displayName}} ({{count1}})</th>
 </tr>
 </ng-template>
 <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-ad>
 <tr>
<td>{{results1}}</td>
</tr>
</ng-template>
</p-table>
```

My Array (results1) is made up of the following:

```
{
"displayName": "Joe Bloggs",
"adgroups": [
    "All Support Information Distribution",
    "All-IT",
    "ASH-RDS",
    "AZCS-PRTG-Users",
    "CORE-IT",
    "DEFENDER_TFA_AUTHENTICATED_USERS",
    "device.approvals",
]
}
```

Errors:

cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'displayName')

The table body gives this error:

ROR Error: NG0901

Any Hell would be great

I've tried to put the array in it's own array with no other data and I get the same error, I'm fairly new to angular and primeng I have done this a similar way before and it's worked, I've not used an array for the table body data before so I'm guessing that's where I'm going wrong